# Why did the Byzantines not try to recover Syria during the war between Ali and Muawiya?

Tags: middle-east, islam, byzantine-empire, syria, umayyad-caliphate

After the Caliph Othman get killed there was period of instability in the Islamic state for more than five years, and Syria was just taken by Muslims before around twenty years.

Why did the Byzantines not take the chance and try to recapture either Syria or Egypt from the Muslims?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they had just lost the battle of Masts to Muawiya bin abu sufyan  in the previous year (655). The emperor Constans II was almost killed.

And notice, when the pressure from the East was really weaker, in 668, he fought the Slavs to the North. And only in 659 "he campaigned far to the east, taking advantage of a rebellion against the Caliphate in Medina. The same year he concluded peace with the Arabs."

He had too little resources for too many problems. And simply couldn't recover Syria.

Comment: Perhaps you mean Medi**n**a? I can't edit because the change is too small, and you have put the sentence in a quote, so it might be verbatim.

Comment: The problem is that I have taken that from wiki as is... Was there some rebellion in Medina or not - I don't know. If you are sure about Medina, I will do the edition. Are you?

Comment: I have corrected medina name and to make it possible I have added muawia full name

Comment: @Gangnus If you are talking about Murder of Uthman, then the Revolt was in Medina. Rebels ruled the streets for a few days until disbanding after murder of Caliph Uthman. If you are talking about the Civil war that ensued when Governor of Syria, Muawiya refused to accept the authority of newly elected Caliph Ali until murderers of Uthman were punished, then that rebellion was centered in Damascus.

Comment: @NSNoob Thank you. Really, number of named mutinies in the Civil war of Mohammed's successors is not important. The main problem is that the  real reason can't be put here because the Gumilev's works are totally unknown in the English world.

Comment: Muawiya is also reported to have said: "If Byzantines attacked [Islamic state], first soldier from Ali's army will be Muawiya!"